# Add another folder structure with Wix installer

Tags: c#, wix

I have a wix installer for a project I have recently completed.

I am wanting the installer to also check if a current folder structure exists elsewhere on the target computer, and if not then create it. Other applications may have already created some or all of the new structure.

So for example. I install to c:\Programs, but I have an additional folder in c:\HomeMadeApps\ThisApp with a number for folders in there like reports, exports etc. It's likely c:\HomeMadeApps will exist, but not guaranteed, so I just want to add the folders (empty) if they don't already exist.

Would anyone be able to point out how I should go about doing this? This is my first time using wix and I'm not 100% sure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directory already exists, the installer will simply install to it.  If they don't, the directories will get created.

I've just tested this to confirm.

The existing contents of the directories are only overwritten if the files have the same name as those added by the installer.

Comment: At the moment I'm adding the directories like you would for the location of the files I am installing. But I am not actually installing anything to these folders and they are not being created.

Comment: There should be a CreateFolder tag within your component tag when you want a directory created (specified by the parent Directory tag). Could you provide a snippet of your directory and feature tags please as am a little confused when you say you're not installing anything to the directories. Thanks

Comment: I realise now I needed the createfolder tags under a single component and doing so has fixed my issue. Thanks. I have marked this as answer because the information was useful, and after testing can confirm it does not overwrite as you said.